# How to disable repair option in visual studio installer

Tags: visual-studio-setup

How we can disable repair / remove option in visual studio (2008) installer. I just want install & uninstall options only. Is it possible to hide that window from installer?

I have tried this with orca; but no yield.

Then I tried to set custom action condition, that too didn't work.
[image]

[image]

Still my installer shows the Repair/Remove dialog if it is already installed.

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio Installer, I found just one way of doing it: **create a custom action** at the *Install* step. In that custom action write code to **create the following registry values**:

```
Key: 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{GUID-THAT-CORRESPONDS-TO-YOUR-PRODUCTCODE}

Values:
NoRepair = dword:00000001
NoModify = dword:00000001
```

That's it. After inserting these values in the registry the "Repair" button disappears from the Add/Remove Programs screen. No custom action *conditions* required.

**Note**: for a 32-bit software running on the Win64 platform the registry path is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\...
```